# mariadb cluster synced but one node shows size=0

Tags: mariadb, cluster-computing, galera

I use mariadb 10.5 with galera 4. I have a 3 node cluster which worked perfectly for the past 6 months. Lately I have been having problems with very cpu intensive query and had to kill that process. One of the nodes (n1) went out of sync so I recreated it. Everything synced perfectly but since that day n1 shows wsrep_cluster_size=0 and the rest of them show wsrep_cluster_size=3.
After a couple of days I decided to stop n2 and n3 to recreate it from n1. Again everything went smoothly but now n3 shows wsrep_cluster_size=0 and n1,n2 show wsrep_cluster_size=3.
I have no idea what's going on. I've checked all the logs and manually checked all the tables and everything seems ok. Data is synced and database is working just fine.

Heres is my configuration

```
[mysqld]

binlog_format                       = ROW
bind-address                        = 0.0.0.0

# Galera Provider Configuration

wsrep_on                            = ON
wsrep_provider                      = /usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so

# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name                  = cluser


wsrep_cluster_address               = gcomm://10.0.0.2,10.0.0.3,10.0.0.4
wsrep_node_address                  = 10.0.0.2
wsrep_node_name                     = n1

# Galera Synchronization Configuration

wsrep_sst_method                    = rsync

log_error                           = /var/lib/mysql/node.log

default_storage_engine              = InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode            = 2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog      = 1
innodb_file_per_table               = 1
#innodb_thread_concurrency          = 0
innodb_buffer_pool_size             = 10G
#innodb_log_buffer_size             = 64M
innodb_flush_method                 = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size                = 2G
innodb_log_files_in_group           = 2
wsrep_slave_threads                 = 5
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog      = 1
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode            = 2

skip-name-resolve

lc-messages-dir                     = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size                     = 16M
max_connections                     = 300
wait_timeout                = 20
max_allowed_packet                  = 16M
thread_stack                        = 192K
thread_cache_size                   = 8

# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit                   = 1M
query_cache_size                    = 16M

expire_logs_days                    = 10
max_binlog_size                     = 100M
```

Here is my SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep%' for 3 nodes

https://pastebin.com/GXj0c38R

And logs

https://pastebin.com/YxJBcguK

Comment: First check the `wsrep_cluster_state_uuid` status variable is the same on all nodes. If it is, good, edit the question and include the node 3 error logs and `show global status like 'wsrep_%'`

Comment: @danblack I updated my question with logs and wsrep output

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug. Please report it on [MariaDB JIRA](https://jira.mariadb.org).

In addition to the `wsrep_cluster_size`=0 on n3, `wsrep_cluster_conf_id` is uninitialised (and not the 23 like other nodes) and `wsrep_cluster_state_uuid` is blank.

For a synced node I'd expect these to have consistent values on all nodes.